# How to stop a Velocity animation using "promise-style"

Tags: velocity.js

I'm using Velocity with promise (Without jQuery...):

```
var Velocity = require('velocity-animate');
var animation = Velocity(document.getElementById('some-id'), { opacity: 0 });
```

How can I arbitrary stop this animation since `animation` returns a promise ?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop any running animation on a dom element using utility function, all you need to do is pass dom element as first parameter and "stop" as second parameter, `Velocity(document.getElementById('some-id'),"stop")`.

See this working example

```js
var a = Velocity(document.getElementById('rect'),{opacity:0},3000);

setTimeout(function(){
 Velocity(document.getElementById('rect'),"stop");
},1000);
```

```css
#rect{
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div id="rect">
  
</div>
```

As you can see promise a is not used to stop animation.

Comment: Thank you!

I really like Velocity, but the fact "animation instances" are attached to DOM elements leaves me perplex.